# Catalina-utility-1 and Catalina-utility-2 excessive memory allocation

Tags: tomcat9

What are these `Catalina-utility-X` threads and why do they burn through so much heap? They consume 20x more memory than my worker thread, which I was trying to debug because I thought *it* was memory-intensive.

[image]

This snapshot is taken on a tomcat instance on my Eclipse IDE, which is receiving zero http traffic - only doing the work on that worker thread (or so I thought).

Comment: Hi, did you find any info regarding this? I get session invalidation to a live session from Catalina-utility thread. I can't find info about this issue. Tomcat 9.0.39.

Comment: No, I didn't...

Comment: you can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68812689/tomcats-catalina-utility-threads-are-periodically-using-high-cpu-and-memory hope it will help you