# Tomcat's Catalina utility threads are periodically using high CPU and memory

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling, heap-memory, cpu-usage

We have a webapp that uses on average 20% CPU when idle, with no network traffic or any kind of requests.
It is running on Java 11, Tomcat 9, Spring Framework 5.3, Hibernate 5.4.
However the issues I will describe below were true on Java 8, Tomcat 8.5, Spring 4.3 and Hibernate 4. as well.
I tried to profile the application using JFR and JMC, and I experimented with a lot of configurations.
[image]
In the image above it looks like catalina-utility-1 and catalina-utility-2 threads wake up periodically and for a few seconds use a lot of CPU.
Also there seems to be a huge amount of memory allocations done by these threads, 30+ GB in total in the sampled 5 minutes interval.

For this profiling I've configured JFR to record everything at maximum, all options enabled.

[image]

When I tried to dig deeper into the details by looking at the Method Profiling details, I observed that it seems to be related to `org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource()`.

So I started to read about Tomcat caching and tried out different parameters to tune it via the `context.xml` file like this:

```
<Context>
  <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
  <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
  <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
  <Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="3024000" cacheObjectMaxSize="10240" cacheTtl="10000"/>
</Context>
```

In this particular example, which is the one used for the JFR profiling, I increased cache size to 3GB and `cacheTtl` to 10 seconds. I thought that a larger cache and larger TTL would effect the interval of the CPU spikes because I suspected Tomcat was checking the cache (originally 1G in size) every 5 seconds which is the default.
However, whatever values I set for cache size or ttl, the periodical CPU spikes are identical.
And the cache size is big enough to hold whatever Tomcat wants to put in there because I increased the value after we saw warnings in the logs. Anyways, 1GB is enough to get rid of the warnings.

I also experimented with heap sizes ranging from 1 to 5GB, the profiling above was done with a 5GB heap size. I can't really go above this value without starting to hit physical memory limits.

We use G1GC as our garbage collector since the Java 8 days. Tuning its parameters did not effect CPU usage.
I also tried out ParallelGC and SerialGC but the CPU usage pattern remained unchanged.

Searching Google for this kind of issues lead to no results and I am totally stuck on what else could I try or what else should I look at.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

It seems like I had a formatting issue originally, and the opening `<context>` tag was missing from the `context.xml` when parsed. Fixed it.

I also tried, as suggested with `<Context reloadable="false">` so that reloadable is explicitly set to false. It had absolutely no effect.

Is it possible to set the reloadable flag from anywhere else? I am speculating maybe some other file or setting applies it even if in `context.xml` it is set to `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack trace in your images contains a call to [`Loader#modified`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Loader.html#modified--) and is only possible if you set the `reloadable` property of your context to `true`:

```xml
<Context reloadable="true">
...
</Context>
```

As described in [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes):

> Set to `true` if you want Catalina to monitor classes in `/WEB-INF/classes/` and `/WEB-INF/lib` for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is very useful during application development, but it requires **significant runtime overhead** and is not recommended for use on deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for this attribute is *false*.

(emphasis mine).

Set `reloadable` to `false` (or delete the attribute) to get rid of the overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It didn't work. I updated my answer and fixed a formatting issue that hid the initial `<context>` tag.

Comment: Did you check all possible locations? This can be set in `conf/Catalina/localhost/<appname>.xml`, `webapps/<appname>/META-INF/context.xml`, `conf/Catalina/localhost/context.xml.default` and `conf/context.xml` (all folders relative to `$CATALINA_BASE`).

Comment: You are a genius Piotr! It seems like that 7 years ago someone on the project though it would be a good idea to have a context.xml in the `webapps/root/META-INF` folder and he set `reloadable="true"` on it. I am working on this project for about 6 years now, I never touched or known about that `context.xml` file inside the git repository of our project. Amazing! CPU usage is basically zero now.

Comment: Changing reloadable from true to false brought CPU usage significantly down. This was a life saver. Thank you so much.