# Is it possible for tomcat's autoDeploy to redeploy unpacked directory

Tags: java, tomcat, web-deployment

I understand that a running Tomcat can redeploy web app if a new .WAR file is copied to webapps dir.

However, in development mode, it is faster to just deploy compiled classes, and base on the document from tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html, it is possible to deploy web app on Tomcat by just copying the compiled classes and resources to Tomcat's webapps dir.

My question, is it possible for Tomcat to autoDeploy if new compiled classes get changed in the webapps dir?

Comment: Do you mean reload the app when something changes?

Comment: @LMC: correct, I have accepted the other answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `reloadable` attributes on the context element (cf. [context container](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes)). This will regularly scan **all** the files in your web application and cause a reload if something changed. This is very useful during development, but very heavy in production (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68812689/11748454)).

The [`autoDeploy` setting](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes) you mentioned in your question causes a redeployment (and hence a reload) of your application **only** if the WAR file or XML deployment descriptor change:

> This flag value indicates if Tomcat should check periodically for new or updated web applications while Tomcat is running. If true, Tomcat periodically checks the `appBase` and `xmlBase` directories and deploys any new web applications or context XML descriptors found. **Updated web applications or context XML descriptors will trigger a reload of the web application.**

(emphasis mine)

If the `reloadable` attribute does not suit your needs, there is a third solution: by using [`WatchedResources`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Nested_Components) you can monitor only some of the application files and cause a reload, when they change.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I'm looking for.